# Filter Table per columb

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code here which filtering table doesn't work, then I want the status filter with checkbox, what I have to do?, please help me!

```js
var $rows = $('tbody > tr'),
    $filters = $('#filter_table input');

$filters.on("keyup", function () {
    var $i = $filters.filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
    }),
        len = $i.length;

    if (len === 0) return $rows.show();

    var cls = '.' + $i.map(function () {
        return this.className
    }).get().join(',.');

    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
        return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function () {
            var content = this.textContent,
                inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val();

            return content.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) > -1;

        }).length === len;
    }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default" id="filter_table">
  Input here to Search <br>
                      <input type='text' class='Program' id='Program' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Program" />
                      <input type='text' class='Year' id='Year' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Year" />
                      <input type='text' class='Province' id='Province' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Province" />
                      <input type='text' class='LGU' id='LGU' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="LGU" />
                      <input type='text' class='Barangay' id='Barangay' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Barangay" />
                      <input type='text' class='Project' id='Project' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Project" />
                      <input type='text' class='Allocation' id='Allocation' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Allocation" />
                      <input type='text' class='Status' id='Status' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Status" />
</div>

<table border='1' class="table table-hover" id='products'>
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th width="10px">Program
                      </th>
                      <th width="10px">Year
                      </th>
                      <th width="20px">Province
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Municipality/LGU
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Barangay
                      </th>
                      <th  width="30px">Project
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Allocation
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Status
                      </th>
                      <th  width="5px">PA%
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                      <td width="10px">Program1
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px">2012
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Province1
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Municipality/LGU1
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">Barangay1
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px">Project1
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">200000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">completed
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">100%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10px">Program1
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px">2013
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Province2
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Municipality/LGU2
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">Barangay2
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px">Project2
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">500000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">ongoing
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">50%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10px">Program3
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px">2014
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Province3
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Municipality/LGU3
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">Barangay3
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px">Project3
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">6000000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">suspended
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">0%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10px">Program4
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px">2016
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Province4
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Municipality/LGU4
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">Barangay4
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px">Project4
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">1000000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">cancelled
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">0%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you consider using a plugin for tables like https://datatables.net/?

Comment: Nope, i just want to be just like that, actually the only thing i want is the selection of the status, i want it to be a drop down with check boxes where i can filter multiple value, if there is another way i would like to try it, Thanks!

Comment: If so, why do you have multiple inputs?

Comment: I have multiple inputs in order to filter a specific data, in status field i want one or more value to be filter, example, what if i want to print data which are the completed and ongoing and suspended, then this data should be the only data to be printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done in your javaScript / Jquery side is correct. You missed to add the relevant class names to your HTML. I added classes for `year` (and I made a change to have 2 records for 2012) and `allocation` and it seems working.

Try searching with `year = 2012` and `allocation = 200000`

```js
var $rows = $('tbody > tr'),
    $filters = $('#filter_table input');

$filters.on("keyup", function () {
    var $i = $filters.filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
    }),
        len = $i.length;

    if (len === 0) return $rows.show();

    var cls = '.' + $i.map(function () {
        return this.className
    }).get().join(',.');

    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
        return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function () {
            var content = this.textContent,
                inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val();

            return content.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) > -1;

        }).length === len;
    }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default" id="filter_table">
  Input here to Search <br>
                      <input type='text' class='Program' id='Program' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Program" />
                      <input type='text' class='Year' id='Year' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Year" />
                      <input type='text' class='Province' id='Province' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Province" />
                      <input type='text' class='LGU' id='LGU' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="LGU" />
                      <input type='text' class='Barangay' id='Barangay' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Barangay" />
                      <input type='text' class='Project' id='Project' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Project" />
                      <input type='text' class='Allocation' id='Allocation' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Allocation" />
                      <input type='text' class='Status' id='Status' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Status" />
</div>

<table border='1' class="table table-hover" id='products'>
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th width="10px">Program
                      </th>
                      <th width="10px">Year
                      </th>
                      <th width="20px">Province
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Municipality/LGU
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Barangay
                      </th>
                      <th  width="30px">Project
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Allocation
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Status
                      </th>
                      <th  width="5px">PA%
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                      <td width="10px">Program1
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2012
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Province1
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Municipality/LGU1
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">Barangay1
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px">Project1
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Allocation'>200000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">completed
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">100%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10px">Program1
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2012
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Province2
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Municipality/LGU2
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">Barangay2
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px">Project2
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Allocation'>500000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">ongoing
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">50%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10px">Program3
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2014
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Province3
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Municipality/LGU3
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">Barangay3
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px">Project3
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Allocation'>6000000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">suspended
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">0%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10px">Program4
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2016
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Province4
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px">Municipality/LGU4
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">Barangay4
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px">Project4
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Allocation'>1000000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px">cancelled
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">0%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Thank you!, what about the status?, i want one or more value to be filter in status field, example, what if i want to print data which are the completed and ongoing and suspended, then this data should be the only data to be printed

Comment: User can give a comma separated values in the status. You can catch that specific case in the filter. Now don't just compare the values coz you have a list (comma separated). Check for each and it should work.
The given answer solves your actual question though. So consider mark it as accepted or edit your question accordingly. Or you can ask a separate question for that specific case regarding the `status`

Comment: Okay, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed code and working for status as well

fiddle: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/yEOPbz

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $rows = $('tbody > tr'),
    $filters = $('#filter_table input');
    $filters.on("keyup", function () {
        var $i = $filters.filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
        });
        var len = $i.length;
        if (len === 0)
            return $rows.show();
        var cls = '.' + $i.map(function () {
        return this.className;
    }).get().join(',.');
        if(cls.indexOf(",") > -1){
            var array = cls.split(",");
            $.each(array,function(i){
                $rows.hide().filter(function () {
                return $('td', this).filter(function () {//console.log(this);
                    var content = this.textContent,
                        inputVal = $i.filter(array[i]).val();
                    return content.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) > -1;

                }).length == len;
            }).show();
            });
        }else{
         $rows.hide().filter(function () {
            return $('td', this).filter(function () {
                var content = this.textContent,
                 inputVal = $i.filter(cls).val();
                          return content.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            }).length === len;
        }).show();
        }
    });
});
```